# can't pass operation '&' result to cout

Tags: visual-c++

I have two integers and trying to pass them to `cout`.

```
int a =1;
int b= 3;
cout<<a&b;
```

Compiler tells:

```
Error   2   error C2676: binary '&' : 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

But a&b returns int that is understandable for '<<' operator.

Why this error rises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to operators precedence, you need to use parenthesis:

```
cout << (a & b)
```

The `<<` operator binds more tightly than `&`, so omitting the parenthesis makes the 
compiler undertand it as `(cout << a) & b`, which explains the error report: The & operator can't be used with a stream (the returned object from `cout << a)` and an int.

Answer (score 1):

This is a precedence problem, if I'm not mistaken. Try using `cout << (a&b);` and see if it doesn't work a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this: :) or did i misunderstood? (a)

```
int a =1;
int b= 3;
cout<<a << "&" << b;
```